# Snackbar crashes with NullPointerException when using programatically created View

Tags: android, android-snackbar

I know it works with any kind of view from XML, but why doesn't it work when using a programmatically created view?

Here is my code:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(tv, "Welcome to AndroidHive", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
snackbar.show();
```

Here is my errors:

```
*Process: com.cloudents.mysnackbar, PID: 9924
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.<init>(Snackbar.java:180)
    at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.make(Snackbar.java:206)
    at com.cloudents.mysnackbar.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:39)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4442)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18473)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)*
```

Comment: The `View` you pass to the `Snackbar` needs to be attached to an on-screen hierarchy. I would imagine it's throwing the NPE when it tries to find its parent's parent.

Answer (score 1):

you can't use a `TextView`, just instantiated to show a `SnackBar`. What it needs is a *suitable parent* of submitted `View`. If you don't have any or you are unsure about which one pass, use directly `android.R.id.content`,

E.g.

```
Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Welcome to AndroidHive", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: thank you
just to make it clear for other users
the code should look like this:

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for sure you can, if the dynamically created `TextView` is added to your `Layout` before your try to show your `Snackbar`, like here,

```
TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        tv.setText("Button");
        tv.setId(5);
 ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout)).addView(tv);
```

Then you can easily do,

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(tv, "Welcome to AndroidHive", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        snackbar.show();
```

Snackbar will be appeared.

Answer (score 1):

The view in :

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "Welcome to AndroidHive",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
snackbar.show();
```

Is the view to which you would like to add the snackbar view and it is not the snackbar itself so just as @Blackbelt mentioned above if you just want to add the snackbar to the activity use findViewById(android.R.id.content) if on the other hand you would like to modify some content in the snackbar view itself that would look something like :

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Welcome to AndroidHive",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

View snackbarView = snackbar.getView()
TextView snackTextView = (TextView) snackbarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
snackTextView.setTextColor(CUSTOMCOLOR);
// modify anything you want in the view here
snackbar.show();
```

In addition I would like to advise you to add a coordinatorlayout to your main layout and add the snackbar to that so the user has the ability to swipe to dismiss the snackbar.